# Strange combobox behavior in PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have this code which creates a combobox in a PDF file. There are two problems with it.

1. Special characters (like ö) are displayed properly when the combobox is opened but then are not displayable when the combobox is closed.
2. When I open the PDF in Acrobat, change the value and save the PDF, the combobox is somehow gone. When I open the PDF again it is not displayed anymore.

Did I mess up something with the PDFBox classes or what may be the problem?

Here is a picture in the opened state:

[image: opened]

and here is one in the closed state:

[image: closed]

```
    public class ComboTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
        Color color = Color.BLACK;
        float fontSize = 12;

        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);

        document.addPage(page);

        PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(document);
        PDComboBox comboBox = new PDComboBox(acroForm);
        comboBox.setPartialName("test");

        String defaultAppearanceString = "/" + font.getName() + " " + fontSize + " Tf "
                + 0 + " " + 0 + " " + 0 + " rg";
        comboBox.setDefaultAppearance(defaultAppearanceString);

        PDAnnotationWidget widget = new PDAnnotationWidget();
        widget.setRectangle(new PDRectangle(200, 200, 100, 20));
        widget.setAnnotationFlags(4);
        widget.setPage(page);
        widget.setParent(comboBox);

        List<String> exportValues = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> displayValues = new ArrayList<>();

        displayValues.add("öne");
        displayValues.add("two");
        displayValues.add("thrée");

        exportValues.add("1");
        exportValues.add("2");
        exportValues.add("3");


        comboBox.setOptions(exportValues, displayValues);

        List<PDAnnotationWidget> widgets = new ArrayList<>();
        widgets.add(widget);
        try {
            page.getAnnotations().add(widget);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        comboBox.setWidgets(widgets);


        try {
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("test.pdf");
            document.save(output);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    }
```

Comment: re 2), add this to your code: `acroForm.getFields().add(comboBox);
        document.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);`. Where did you get this code?

Comment: I didn't find any examples on the internet so I tried myself. Thanks this worked, now it doesn't disappear anymore.

Comment: re 1), replace font.getName() with "Helv". Not sure why this is so.

Comment: Thanks this worked too!

Comment: Do you know maybe how to get to this "Helv" string from the font class?

Comment: No, this is something unofficial from Adobe. See the answer, that one uses "Helv" but one could also use the name of the font in both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near the end of your code, add this:

```
acroForm.getFields().add(comboBox);
document.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);
```

this makes sure that your acroform and its field is known to the PDF.

Re the special character, replace the name of the Helvetica font with "Helv", which is a standard name for Adobe.

Better, cleaner solution: set up the default resources.

```
PDResources dr = new PDResources();
dr.put(COSName.getPDFName("Helv"), font);
acroForm.setDefaultResources(dr);
```

Instead of "Helv" you can also use `COSName.getPDFName(font.getName())`, but it has to be the same in your default appearance string.

So the full code is now:

```
public class ComboTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
        Color color = Color.BLACK;
        float fontSize = 12;

        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);

        document.addPage(page);

        PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(document);
        PDComboBox comboBox = new PDComboBox(acroForm);
        comboBox.setPartialName("test");

        // Helv instead of Helvetica
        String defaultAppearanceString = "/Helv " + fontSize + " Tf "
                + 0 + " " + 0 + " " + 0 + " rg";
        comboBox.setDefaultAppearance(defaultAppearanceString);

        PDAnnotationWidget widget = new PDAnnotationWidget();
        widget.setRectangle(new PDRectangle(200, 200, 100, 20));
        widget.setAnnotationFlags(4);
        widget.setPage(page);
        widget.setParent(comboBox);

        List<String> exportValues = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> displayValues = new ArrayList<>();

        displayValues.add("öne");
        displayValues.add("two");
        displayValues.add("thrée");

        exportValues.add("1");
        exportValues.add("2");
        exportValues.add("3");

        comboBox.setOptions(exportValues, displayValues);

        List<PDAnnotationWidget> widgets = new ArrayList<>();
        widgets.add(widget);
        try
        {
            page.getAnnotations().add(widget);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        comboBox.setWidgets(widgets);

        // new
        acroForm.getFields().add(comboBox);
        document.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);
        PDResources dr = new PDResources();
        dr.put(COSName.getPDFName("Helv"), font);
        acroForm.setDefaultResources(dr);

        try
        {
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("test.pdf");
            document.save(output);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `dr.put("Helv", font);` doesn't work for me. The first argument needs to be a `COSName`

Comment: fixed (hopefully)